# Immediately invoked function expression causing error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iife

Can someone explain why this could happen?

If I write something like this in a **file** named like `test.js`,

```
const anyObject = {}
(function(){ 
  console.log('hello world!') 
}())
```

run it through console with `$node test.js`

then in the console, a `hello world!` will be printed, but followed with this: 
`TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function`

**Idon't know what exactly happend there, I guess somehow node is taking the function expression as a function call expression ?**

I'm using node `v6.9.1`

Comment: for the love of everything, use semicolons,

Comment: check  your brackets ')'

Comment: IIFE's are commonly demonstrated like `;(function() ...` ... because lazy programmers don't use semicolons where they should ...

Comment: use a linter on your code to pick up such problems ... though, I suspect you'll be sick of "missing semicolon" errors in even the shortest piece of code

Comment: An excellent example of how people get themselves in trouble when they get lazy and leave out the semi-colons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `void` for calling without semicolon.

This forces the expression to evaluate and return `undefined`.

```js
void (function() { 
    console.log('hello world!') 
}());
```

It works even without outer parenthesis.

```js
const anyObject = {}
void function() { 
    console.log('hello world!') 
}();
```

Comment: `const anyObject = {}` unncessary code it's working fine without this line

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh, right. it was the leftover from op's code.

Answer (score 2):

- Use semi colons
- Syntax is different in your IIFE

```js
const anyObject = {};
(function(){ 
  console.log('hello world!');
})();
```